# R httr: POST JSON with curl -d

Tags: json, r, curl, httr

I have to post data to an API using curl; the command looks like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic code" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: token" -d '[JSON data]' "URL" -v
```

I want to do this with R because the JSON data is generated in R.
This is what I have tried, using the package httr:

```
     POST(url = "url",
          accept_json(),
          add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json", "Authorization" = "Basic code",
         "Postman-Token" ="token", "Cache-Control" = "no-cache"),
          body = toJSON(list(text = "Hello World!", level = "Noob")),
          encode = "json",
          authenticate(user = "user", password = "pwd"),
          verbose() )
```

It returns this:

```
POST url HTTP/1.1
-> Host: host
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.43.0 r-curl/0.9.6 httr/1.1.0
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json
-> Content-Type: application/json
-> Authorization: Basic code
-> Postman-Token: token
-> Cache-Control: no-cache
-> Content-Length: 45
-> 
>> {
>>  "text": "Hello World!",
>> "level": "Noob" 
>> }
```

And a HTML error 400 Bad Request.

I have the impression that the body (-d attribute) is somehow wrong, but I can not figure out how to do it right.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure the JSON data is the same in both? I'd recommend setting up both code chunks to POST to a site like http://requestb.in so you can see exactly what's being posted.

Comment: I just entered some fake test data - in reality it is much larger JSON file...
But what's the right ways to post the -d attribute with POST()?

Comment: Well, it's not the same in your R and CURL code. Those two command seem to create very similar requests. Seems more likely to be due to the contents. Compare the content length when you post the data to requestbin

Comment: ok, thanks for the link to requestbin - that was helpful :-)